# Search etc-20 tokens by name on UniSwap

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, uniswap

We’ve created an erc-20 token and deployed it on Eth mainnet and listed plus added liquidity and received the LP’s on UniSwap. At the moment, on UniSwap, we can only search for the token by its 0x... address.

Question: How can we add the token’s symbol( name) and logo on UniSwap in order to be able to search and display the token by name ( in addition to the 0x... address search). Thank you

Comment: Do you list your token in CoinmarketCap or CoinGecko?

Comment: No we didn’t list it on CoinmarketCap or CoinGecko. How would that resolve the ‘search by name’ on UniSwap problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your [answer](https://cryptomarketpool.com/how-to-add-an-image-logo-to-your-crypto-token/)

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. Will look into it. For some reason etherscan team thinks that the token doesn’t meet the network’s profiling ( social media expose etc..) standards... could that be the reason? what’s your take on that view?

Comment: Did you verify your token contract?

Comment: Yes we did verify it. Strange??

Comment: No, i think it's necessary to verify, then add token logo

Comment: I’m sure the contact was verified but will check again. Appreciate your feedback. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, notify me here if problem solves.

Comment: Much appreciated. Tks.